# Why np.bincount(x) is giving 0 at the start?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, numpy, for-loop

I am novice in NumPy and just came across these two functions which count the number of occurrences. So basically what is the difference between them?

I created a list `x= [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6]`
Now, I want to count the number of occurences of the numbers in a list using a for loop or `np.bincount`. I already used counter module but I wanted to try some other methods.

```py
x= [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6]
#Counter(x)
np.bincount(x) = [0 3 3 3 3 3 3]
```

The problem is that `np.bincount` is giving me 0 in the list of output ,`[0 3 3 3 3 3 3]`, and the total numbers in `x` are 6 but bincount gives me 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation for `np.bincount()` [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). The value will always be 1 larger than the maximum number in the array because python is a zero based language and the first number it checks is zero. So in your case you have zero zeroes and [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] gives you seven numbers.

Comment: So,to omit that 0 what should I do because I have to plot a bar graph of these values and its probably a shape mismatch.Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't have an issue. But if you do, you can just index the other numbers after zero using `np.bincount(x)[1:]`